I get a "HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long" because expired cookies are sent, why?
Some users are complaining about errors like this:

"HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long"

After analyzing a HAR file, I'd say that the problem is that the Cookies header is too big, because many expired cookies are being sent. The HAR file contains many entries like these:
{
  "name": "SIGNOUT2ce39f5648a946b6b7ce94ff5603082d",
  "value": "c13skPLROW897KomNQCBbSp70pYeOJy+86nwIRiP1Sacq0P/qqpoBrNpscIXVacquSd6gbuqNod0xHXJJEDBdzcvCTUHkaZuXvIEJq3yiBCyiJyVQXbpnxj0wDZ8BN7SMQSZfYjyuWF0kukJDY71VR5ouvzu3eghMXPAyFR1oVs9YKWSlIPc0ce/10nxhevq0UdAJWYfLItUMI20eBb/1VcFBjkscxzXYNEJj7jKYwedrwy0KAWOdnwRj5uMheKkGVQmDFMBWiJxz9s2aKXjuy3x8LmKGBwcLo3kphhNnnm+8xZP21XQXOwq1fVIMsqyWRJPilG0SKbV47weC3mKrA==",
  "path": "/",
  "domain": "<REDACTED>",
  "expires": "1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z",
  "httpOnly": true,
  "secure": true,
  "sameSite": "None"
},
{
  "name": "SIGNINa6685d5973f34c88bccef056a414bb1b",
  "value": "fEzSLX1gLUhPzPcfUn4SE/VXaTD5pVGFSLDhLwguOOd0lfGWDBMLovZ8AUV9JMva2veGwXOAblX2pynbju14p5w1LZ3vpJm5RLXmti/urrVK9lDNMPHrGVP/fMIiGg5met1TDLJ95kuaV9h023FDX3cjMMnhRw3z/GwXSxeHbJrF/770Il2BcvX6ba21rET5Tgsvz/r3AS5aIrArYMVBBqln1D3lOH0kFP1CEa2fEtY4ksGdyHZ5BkDpyblKdaDh/sflcg+iV+tUSDaOZa0QLG/nbJ4ExutcCPsZBiEUCrQV5RrX13RAzjpCmf6M0fAxvIFN1xsUbP+EfAOrZqpfSdeQoK0nKsL79GTCXhLF8WOeRRZMS9LeyuU244CE09IVlPjtCVV+mrpEtWlv38qq0itWkgII0adUD8srchXbMVFThEZE+ewZ7gF2Ng8FAtFkFnvVdVLIr5pP3yoBr+O01F6IDEVpVJrROr1rLIWcggsKyvdF9VavyP7UWbkiY8G9aY4ZBRrWcdvDCPn4iVB7jA==",
  "path": "/",
  "domain": "<REDACTED>",
  "expires": "1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z",
  "httpOnly": true,
  "secure": true,
  "sameSite": "None"
},
... many more


Why are those cookies sent? Shouldn't they be ignored by the
browser? (Microsoft Edge version 122.0.0.0, running on 64-bit
Windows 10, in this case)
What can I do to prevent fix this issue?

